# Flask and pyautogui

Tags: python, flask, pyautogui

i have made a flask app that has one button and when that button is clicked it perform certain click on screen by pyauto gui using locateonscreen() function but when some else access that app and perform click on that button after clicking sometime it runs accurately sometime it gaves error that image not found some time it gave screen not grab although my app is accessible any where

According to my excpectations it must run every time

Comment: The issue could be different screen resolution by other users.

Comment: Any Solution of it

Comment: start_x, start_y = pyautogui.position()
for i in range(9, 5, -1):
    confidence_level=f"0.{i}"
    print(confidence_level)  
    bold_icon_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('button (2).jpg', confidence=confidence_level) 
    if bold_icon_location: 
        bold_icon_center = pyautogui.center(bold_icon_location)
  pyautogui.click(bold_icon_center)